# Epub page break if element effected move elements to new page together as one

Tags: html, css, epub

In writing a epub file and i have images that are directly related to certain text i have tried putting them in a div as a block and floating but once in the reader the text moves to a new line i want to make sure if the text is moved to a new page the image follows it as if one element.

```
<div id="img_graphics2" class="center">
    <img id="graphics2" src="../images/graphics2.jpg" alt="graphics2"/>
    <p class="imgtxt">Above: Is a storage container</p>
</div>

img_graphics2 {
   display: block;
   float:left;
   width: 76%;
   margin-left: 12%;
   margin-right: 12%;: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add css attribute "page-break-inside:avoid" to containing div

```
<div id="img_graphics2" class="imgtxtdiv">
  <img id="graphics2" src="../images/graphics2.jpg" alt="graphics2"/>
  <p class="imgtxt">Above: Is a storage container</p>
</div>

img_graphics2 {
   display: block;
   float:left;
   width: 76%;
   margin-left: 12%;
   margin-right: 12%;: 
}
.imgtxtdiv {
    page-break-inside:avoid
}
```